# reporting CA per month for each customer in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I should have CA/month/Customer in VBA for a period between A1 and C1

[image]
Can you help me by giving me the steps? The first the second..
Or by giving me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use functions. No need for VBA for that.

Comment: yes! but i don't know what is the first step and the second ...?

Comment: Use =SUM() to summarize.

Comment: yes i know, my problem i don't know the different steps

Comment: Google how to use SUM or go on YouTube. I have no idea what steps you are talking about. Clean up the post and explain it properly if you expect anyone here to understand it.